# Images and Thumbnails in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, image, performance, thumbnails

I want to store the images along with the thumbnails of it. I am storing the images in file system using django. At first, the user will be able to see the thumbnails and after clicking it original images can be seen. I am using postgres database. Also, I have already installed Pillow library. Thumbnail size will be approx 200*200.

Now my questions are:

1. How should I store the thumbnails ? (in database or in file system)
2. How to convert the images to it's thumbnails ? (python library or something else)

If anything better is possible for the mentioned feature please let me know.

P.S.: High performance and lesser page load time is required.

Comment: You can use sorl-thumbnail - Thumbnails for Django https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail

Comment: Also, I have already installed Pillow library. Do I additionally need sorl-thumbnail or easy-thumbanail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are third party apps that do the heavy lifting like [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail) or [easy-thumbnail](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails)

For the first question, storing the image in the system or cdn and the path in the db is the best approach, and that's what django does by default.

Comment: Can you please tell me which is better among these two?

Comment: Also, I have already installed Pillow library. Do I additionally need sorl-thumbnail or easy-thumbanail?

Comment: Pillow allows us to manipulate images, sorl and easy thumbnail are built on top of it to process images and make thumbnail

Comment: They are both good third apps, check the docs to see which one you get the most and use it or check the github stars